# C++ Windows API - How to retrieve font scaling percentage

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to retrieve the **"Make text bigger"** percentage in C++ Windows API application. I know how to retrieve the scaling (DPI) factor, but I also want to include the font scaling percentage (see the attached image, the upper value, not the lower one).

Ultimately, I want to make application that preserves user font and DPI scaling settings in order to fully support accessibility features. Currently, the font is specified in `.rc` file like so

```
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg 2", 0, 0, 0x0
```

but even omitting the FONT statement, the font still does not change when changing "Make text bigger" setting.

[image]

Comment: GetScaleFactorForMonitor ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor

Comment: @Simon Mourier as far as I understand that setting returns the second value only so DPI scaling, and not the font size

Comment: There's a winrt API for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.textscalefactor otherwise the `TextScaleFactor` value in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Accessibility` registry key (not officially documented)

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find it! If you want, post an answer for future reference and some reputation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the "**Make everything bigger**" section, you can use [`GetScaleFactorForMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getscalefactorformonitor)

> Gets the scale factor of a specific monitor.

For the "**Make text bigger**" section, you can use a WinRT static property: [`UISettings.TextScaleFactor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.textscalefactor)

> Gets the value of the system text size setting.

Otherwise the latter can also be read using the `TextScaleFactor`
`DWORD` attribute in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Accessibility` registry key (but this is not officially documented).

Comment: How to get font scaling with C++ without using any .NET library?

Comment: @Somnium - WinRT is not a managed API. It's language-agnostic and has projection for .NET but also for C/C++. I'd use C++/WinRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt

Comment: Is it possible to get it just Windows API, without additional libraries?

Comment: WinRT *is* a Windows API, there's no additional libraries involved

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at two things that **contribute** to the answer, but neither is the answer alone:

- DPI
- Text Scaling

Knowing the user's DPI and Text Scaling preferences do not give you enough information to scale the text properly.

It is incorrect to try to read DPI and/or Text scaling and use that to scale the size of the UI elements.

Lets say you *did* read the values and got back:

- DPI: 96 dpi (i.e. 100%)
- Text Scaling: 1.000 (i.e. 100%)

You might take that to mean that you do not need to scale anything.

That would be wrong.

For example:

- my Windows is configured for 96 dpi and no text scaling
- and yet your application is **supposed** to scale your dialogs by 136%

if you want to be a good Windows developer that honors accessbility and user preferences.

That's because:

- you're not scaling with DPI
- and you're not scaling with Text Scaling

You're supposed to scale based on **font size**. And while:

- dpi
- text scaling

are two things that can affect font size; they're not the only things.

If i configure my Windows to use:

> Georgia 13pt, 96dpi, no text scaling

```
| Font                | DPI      |  Font height (pixels) |
|---------------------|----------|-----------------------|
| MS Shell Dlg 2 8pt  |   96 dpi |                 11 px |
| Georgia 13pt        |   96 dpi |                 17 px |
| Georgia 9pt         |  136 dpi |                 17 px |
| Segoe UI 9pt        |  128 dpi |                 16 px |
| Segoe UI 12pt       |   96 dpi |                 16 px |
```

Then you are **supposed** to scale your UI (text, buttons, listviews, checkboxes, labels, etc) by `17 / 11 = 154.54%`

The correct way is to do what Microsoft asked us to do in the late 1980s, and scale based on the size of the user-interface text. Microsoft called them **dialog units** (DLUs).

### What's a dialog unit?

A dialog is a unit of measure based on the user's preferred font size.
A dialog unit is defined such that the *average character* is 4 dialog
units wide by 8 dialog units high:

[image]

This means that dialog units:

- change with selected font
- changed with selected DPI setting
- are not square

Here's an example of a Windows dialog, with the [recommended Windows DLU layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-layout):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230830-00/?p=108680

I removed the example for C# for you.  Note, you need Windows 10 SDK to do this, but with some work, you can get the last example working with Windows 8.1 SDK.  `IUISettings2` interface can be defined in your own code.

```
// C++/WinRT
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>

double GetTextScaleFactor()
{
    return winrt::Windows::UI::
           ViewManagement::UISettings().TextScaleFactor();
}

// C++/CX

double GetTextScaleFactor()
{
    return (ref new Windows::UI::
        ViewManagement::UISettings())->TextScaleFactor;
}

// C++/WRL
#include <Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>

HRESULT GetTextScaleFactor(double* value)
{
    *value = 1.0;

    using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
    using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;

    ComPtr<IInspectable> instance;
    HRESULT hr = RoActivateInstance(HStringReference(
        RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UISettings).Get(),
        &instance);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    ComPtr<ABI::Windows::UI::ViewManagement::IUISettings2>
        settings2;
    hr = instance.As(&settings2);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = settings2->get_TextScaleFactor(value);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}
```