# C++ Windows API - How to retrieve font scaling percentage on Windows 10

Tags: c++, manifest, text-size

My goal is to be able to adjust the font size at runtime in a C++ app, based on the monitor resolution.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785427/c-windows-api-how-to-retrieve-font-scaling-percentage), it's explained how to get the font scaling percentage, but the suggested function `GetScaleFactorForMonitor` requires Windows 8.1. My C++ app must run on Windows 7 or higher. I have tried several proposed solutions based on getting the ratio of device caps parameters, but they all get 1.0 on a Windows 10 system where the Windows "Make everything bigger" setting is 150%.

Per the MS docs, Visual Studio is adding "dpiAware" to the manifest (this is a setting I can change). Probably because the app is being built on a Windows 7 system, the VS-generated manifest does not include Windows 10 as a supported O/S. If I add the lines

```
       <!--This Id value indicates the application supports Windows 10, Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019-->
      <supportedOS Id="{{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
```

to the manifest, when I run the app on Windows 10, I get a "side-by-side" error.

How can I get this "make everything bigger" and the "make text bigger" settings on a Windows 7 or 10 system?

Build system: 64-bit Windows 7, Visual Studio 2019 16.7.7  Run system: Windows 7 or later

Comment: Reading your question I'm not entirely confident you read the post you linked right (or well maybe I didn't read it right?). "Make everything bigger" is the "DPI setting" (which historically has had settings 100% - 96 dpi; 125% - 120 dpi; 150 % - 144 dpi; this is accessed using the HDC's dpi values. `GetScaleFactorForMonitor` seems to be associated with this setting, but I don't know why you would want to use that function over using the DPI values). "Make text bigger" appears to a "new" WinRT thing (and thus didn't exist in Windows 7), and is read with `UISettings.TextScaleFactor`.

Comment: I need my app to adjust font sizes to match the user's settings. In Win 7, as you noted, there are just the choices 100, 125 and 150%. In Win 10 (and maybe Win 8.1, don't care; no one is going to be using 8 or 8.1), there are the two settings. What I need to know in either case is the desired font size in pixels, which is not the same as the dpi of the monitor. For example, on a 3840x2160 monitor, I have the "make everything bigger" set to 150%, and the correct appearance is obtained by multiplying the font size (height) by 1.5. But how to get that user-set 1.5 factor? (cont)

Comment: (conti) `TextScaleFactor` is a .NET thing, and I am using MFC only.

Comment: > `For example, on a 3840x2160 monitor, I have the "make everything bigger" set to 150%...` "Make everything bigger" *is* the DPI setting. You are confusing the two settings. And `TextScaleFactor` (i.e. "Make text bigger") is not a .NET thing, it's a WinRT thing. This is primarily for UWP development, which applies to .NET and C++ (via C++/WinRT); it is intended for UWP apps, not for Win32 apps (although nobody stops you from using it in a Win32 app, of course, but you'll have to call into the WinRT library, or read the undocumented registry key).

Comment: DPI is an acronym for dots per inch, and it normally refers to the display on the monitor. It's true that this can be changed in the hardware or by WIndows, but that's not what is happening. Windows adjusts the size of everything by using different fonts and control, etc sizes, but the display shows these at the same number of dots (pixels) per physical inch. So the question remains: how can I get access to the 1.5 scale factor set by the user.

Comment: >`but that's not what is happening.` My dude that is *exactly* what's happening. **"Make everything bigger" is the DPI setting.** It affects what comes out of [`GetDpiForMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor) and all the other DPI aware Win32 functions. [See also this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows). The percentage number is just a silly UI thing; 100 % refers to 96 dpi.

Comment: [Here is another 3rd party article discussing DPI-awareness](https://building.enlyze.com/posts/writing-win32-apps-like-its-2020-part-3/)

Comment: Tnx for the references. I had seen the MS one, but the 3rd-party one is useful. Unfortunately, I am running into two problems that prevent me from using these. (1) `GetDpiForMonitor` is not available for W7; (2) The proposed soln of using `GetDeviceCaps` doesn't take the user-set "make bigger" into account. See the original post.

Comment: >`(2) The proposed soln of using GetDeviceCaps doesn't take the user-set "make bigger" into account. ` It does; you must be doing something else wrong. Your application needs to have a manifest which declares DPI awareness (either simple `dpiAware`=`true`, or the newer PerMonitorV2). Otherwise `GetDeviceCaps` with `LOGPIXELSX/Y` will always return 96 due to DPI virtualization. Furthermore, on Windows 7, you must log out and back in (no fast user switching, *real* logout). Plus, `GetDeviceCaps` will always return the DPI of your *primary display*. It does not support per-monitor DPI settings.

Comment: Also note that in your situation, you probably want to declare both `dpiAware` and `dpiAwareness` in the manifest. Windows 7 doesn't recognize `dpiAwareness`, but it will fall back to `dpiAware`.

Comment: Here is a project demonstrating the APIs: https://github.com/HMd38kvVVlMQEfcb/DpiAwarenessCheck  I tested it under Windows 7 and Windows 10 (with multiple monitors and different DPI settings).

Comment: My manifest does have `DPIaware set`. But it does not have Windows 10 manifested; I think the latter is why `GetDeviceCaps` does not return the 1.5 x 96 dpi value Windows is set to. See my original post for the manifest issues.

Comment: (1) You don't need `supportedOS` for this to work, and (2) your GUID has two `{`, which probably results in a parse error, and (3) `dpiAware` `true` will make it work on Windows 10 as well. The only downside is that it won't use a per-monitor setting. Instead it will use the primary screen's setting. **Download the ResourceHacker tool and compare the manifest to the one in the .exe I've provided in that github repo (under Releases).**

Comment: Result from your DPI awareness check solution. Run on W7 (size=100%): `GetDeviceCaps`: 96x96; `GetDpiForMonitor` / `GetDPI Awareness level`: shcore/GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext doesn't exist on this system. Run on W10 (size=150%): `GetDeviceCaps`: 144x144; `GetDpiForMonitor`: 144x144; `GetDPI Awareness level`: DPI_AWARENESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE. So your solution is working perfectly. The only difference between the manifests is you have `PerMonitorV2` for `dpiAwareness`. I will try changing my manifest to include this. I might add, my app is ASCII, not Unicode as yours is, if this matters.

Comment: Out of scope for this question: It's actually ANSI, not ASCII. And don't do ANSI applications in 2020. You will have so many unnecessary problems once your program is running on a system with a different locale. People may not even be able to open a file if there's a special character in the path. The only reason you'd ever want ANSI is if you need your thing to run on Windows 98 and earlier. -- I don't know if that has anything to do with DPI awareness though. I don't think so.

Comment: There is a difference between ASCII (a 7-bit character set) and ANSI (one selection or "code page" of an an 8-bit character set). There's another reason for not using Unicode: the program was written before Unicode was available, and changing the hundreds of source files to Unicode would be a momentous task, not to mention the incompatibility of years of data. PS, It's 2021!

Comment: That's fair. [But the non-unicode winapi functions (i.e. functions ending with `...A`) stand for ANSI, not ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api)

Answer (score 1):

After discussing in the comments, it turns out your actual problem is that you don't declare DPI awareness in your manifest correctly.

You need to **merge this into your manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
</assembly>
```

Explanation:

`dpiAware` `true` is recognized by Windows 7 *and* Windows 10, and declares **system-wide DPI awareness** (`DPI_AWARENESS_SYSTEM_AWARE`). System-wide means that it assumes that all applications on all monitors use the same DPI setting).

`dpiAwareness` is recognized by Windows 10 (Windows 7 ignores it) and, if present, supersedes `dpiAware`. It declares **per-monitor DPI awareness** (`DPI_AWARENESS_PER_MONITOR_AWARE`), which means that each monitor can have different DPI settings and your application must handle that correctly.<sup>(2)</sup>

If you do not include this manifest, Windows will *virtualize* the DPI, meaning it will act *as if* the DPI setting is always at 96 (100%), and then Windows merely scales the bitmaps (blurry). This is a compatibility measure that ensures that applications which do not implement DPI code can still appear bigger.

---

Then, **on Windows 7**, you get the scaling factor using the `GetDeviceCaps` function with `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY`, and dividing the result by `96` (because 96 dpi is "100%").<sup>(1)</sup> This will give you the DPI setting of the main monitor. `GetDeviceCaps` has been *the* way to get this setting since Windows XP. This will also do fine on Windows 10 *if and only if* you do *not* declare DPI awareness *per monitor*.

**On Windows 10**, *if* you declare DPI awareness *per monitor*, `GetDeviceCaps` will *not* suffice because it only returns the DPI setting for the *main display*. But if you declare `PerMonitorV2`, then you are obliged to implement per-monitor DPI correctly. To do this, you can call `GetDpiForWindow`, or `MonitorFromWindow` + `GetDpiForMonitor`.

Since you want your executable to run on both Windows 7 and Windows 10, you cannot link against `GetDpiForWindow` and `GetDpiForMonitor` because those functions do not exist in Windows 7. You will need **manually link at runtime using `GetProcAddress`**.

---

**To merge the manifest**, you can use the *Manifest Tool* in Visual Studio (Project Properties -> Manifest Tool). Put the entire manifest XML text from above into a file (e.g. `DpiAwareness.manifest`), and specify that under **Manifest Tool** -> **Input and Output** -> **Additional Manifest Files**.

---

As for the "Make text bigger" accessibility setting: It is a relatively new WinRT setting that is meant for UWP apps. You're not really expected to use it in Win32 applications, so it's going awkward in Win32. I can't help you there because I hate all things UWP. UWP can go die in a fire.

---

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> I have never seen a `DISPLAY` device with a non-`1:1` aspect ratio though. It is probably only useful for printers. The fact that `GetDpiForWindow`, which is the most modern of the mentioned functions, only returns one number, suggests that it is probably safe to assume that the DPI in X direction will always be equal to the DPI in Y direction (on `DISPLAY` devices).</sub>

<sub><sup>(2)</sup> Note that there is also `dpiAwareness` `PerMonitor` (without V2). This is more or less a now-obsolete hack that came with Windows 8. Don't bother with it.</sub>

Comment: Turns out there was nothing wrong with my manifest. VS adds dpiAware=true by default, and I verified in my final comment that my manifest included it. What am using now is the values from `GetDeviceCaps` as in your example soln (which now seems to be gone from GitHub), and it works perfectly. Tnx so much for your patient help and explanations.

Comment: @Woody20 VS doesn't add DPI awareness automatically. Maybe you have **Manifest Tool** -> **Input and Output** -> **DPI awareness** set. That setting can add one of the two tags to the manifest, but not both. I find that setting rather convoluted and hidden.